# I am working to generate nifty_layout in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ubuntu 13.10 Terminal
Rails 4.2
Ruby 2.1
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
 
Command => 
`rails generate nifty_layout`
result=> `Could not find generator 'nifty_layout'. Maybe you meant 'nifty:layout' or 'nifty:config' or 'nifty:scaffold'
Run`rails generate --help`for more options.`
Please provide a solution.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Add this to your gemfile: `gem 'nifty-generators', group: :development`
2. Run: `bundle install`
3. And then use `rails generate nifty:layout`